# Pgfplots - plot not reaching axis: gaps vs domain and samples

Tags: pgfplots

Consider the example below, which works just fine, but we do not quite understand why.

If we  instead use `domain=-1:1` we get gaps:

[image]

Whereas `domain=-2:2` gives us

[image]

As we wanted.

At the same time if we in the `domain=-2:2` case instead use `samples=1000` we get

[image]

which are different gaps than the first image.

What exactly is going on there and why does the `domain=-2:2` + `samples=1001` work in this case?

If relevant, this is compiled using TL17 frozen.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  >={Latex[round]},
  declare function={
    f(\x,\k)=(1-abs(\x)^(\k))^(1/\k);
  },
}

\pgfplotsset{
  setup/.style={
    very thick,
    width=5cm,
    domain=-2:2, 
    samples=1001, 
    -,
    unbounded coords=jump,
    no marks,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
%    ticks=none,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = -1.2,
    xmax=1.4,
    ymin=-1.2,
    ymax=1.4,
    every axis y label/.style={
      at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
      anchor=south,
    },
  },
  every non boxed x axis/.append style={
    axis line style=->
  },
  every non boxed y axis/.append style={
    axis line style=->
  },
}

\begin{document}
    % q=2
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        setup,
        ylabel={$q=2$},
        ]
        \addplot[blue] {f(x,2)};
        \addplot[blue] {-f(x,2)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \qquad 
%q=3
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        setup,
        ylabel={$q=3$},
        ]
        \addplot[red] {f(x,3)};
        \addplot[red] {-f(x,3)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad    
    %q=4
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        setup,
        ylabel={$q=4$},
        ]
        \addplot[red] {f(x,4)};
        \addplot[red] {-f(x,4)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad    
% %q=6
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        setup,
        ylabel={$q=6$},
        ]
        \addplot[red] {f(x,6)};
        \addplot[red] {-f(x,6)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When you have odd number of samples, the last point is hit. Otherwise it is a miss and the last point is not computed.

Comment: It might be a better way to work with logarithms to decrease the fixed point computation error. I haven't tested it though

Comment: @percusse that does not really explain why the doubled sized domain is needed

Comment: Most likely I am missing something but if you increase the domain beyond `-1:1` some parts get drawn twice because the function is `f(\x,\k)=(1-abs(\x)^(\k))^(1/\k);`.  I am actually surprised to see that pgfplots does not strike if you ask it to take the logarithm of a negative number.

Comment: @marmot that is probably because of the `    unbounded coords=jump`

Comment: Yes (and no, why is the 3rd root of `-0.5`, say, unbounded?). I think that the cleanest way may be to draw a parametric plot that doesn't have this problem, perhaps that's what @percusse means by taking the logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that the functions are no longer real if `|x|>1` and `k>1`. If you filter out the problematic values, there are no problems.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  >={Latex[round]},
  declare function={
    f(\x,\k)=ifthenelse((1-abs(\x)^(\k))<0,0,(1-abs(\x)^(\k))^(1/\k));
  },
}

\pgfplotsset{
  setup/.style={
    very thick,
    width=5cm,
    domain=-2:2, 
    samples=1000, 
    -,
    unbounded coords=jump,
    no marks,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
%    ticks=none,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = -1.2,
    xmax=1.4,
    ymin=-1.2,
    ymax=1.4,
    every axis y label/.style={
      at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
      anchor=south,
    },
  },
  every non boxed x axis/.append style={
    axis line style=->
  },
  every non boxed y axis/.append style={
    axis line style=->
  },
}

\begin{document}
    % q=2
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        setup,
        ylabel={$q=2$},
        ]
        \addplot[blue] ({ifthenelse(abs(x)>1,sign(x),x)},{f(x,2)});
        \addplot[blue] ({ifthenelse(abs(x)>1,sign(x),x)},{-f(x,2)});
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \qquad 
%q=3
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        setup,
        ylabel={$q=3$},
        ]
        \addplot[red] ({ifthenelse(abs(x)>1,sign(x),x)},{f(x,3)});
        \addplot[red] ({ifthenelse(abs(x)>1,sign(x),x)},{-f(x,3)});
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad    
    %q=4
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        setup,
        ylabel={$q=4$},
        ]
        \addplot[red] ({ifthenelse(abs(x)>1,sign(x),x)},{f(x,4)});
        \addplot[red] ({ifthenelse(abs(x)>1,sign(x),x)},{-f(x,4)});
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad    
% %q=6
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        setup,
        ylabel={$q=6$},
        ]
        \addplot[red] ({ifthenelse(abs(x)>1,sign(x),x)},{f(x,6)});
        \addplot[red] ({ifthenelse(abs(x)>1,sign(x),x)},{-f(x,6)});
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A bit simpler would be to declare the function as `f(\x,\k)=max(0,1-abs(\x)^(\k))^(1/\k);`, right?

Comment: @StefanPinnow Yes, sure, thanks. One could make things even simpler, by drawing a parametric plot of `({sign(cos(x))*((abs(cos(x)))^(1/k)},{sign(sin(x))*((abs(sin(x)))^(1/k)})` but this is not the point I wanted to make here.